# Is $\omega$ -consistency, soundess, or completeness expressible in the language of arithmetic?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, incompleteness

Obviously through the second incompleteness theorem consistency is expressible in La, I was wondering if $\omega$ -consistency and completeness were the same and how so. I know soundness is not but I don't know why not so if someone could explain that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Working in some fixed appropriate theory $T$ (e.g. PA), completeness and $\omega$-consistency are expressible for the same reason consistency is: because **provability** is expressible. That is, there is a formula $Prov(x)$ such that $\mathbb{N}\models Prov(k)$ iff $k$ is the Godel number of a theorem of $T$. With this we have:

- $T$ is consistent iff $\exists x(\neg Prov(x))$.
- $T$ is complete iff $\forall x(Prov(x)\vee Prov(x'))$, where "$x'$" is the definable function corresponding to negation (that is, $k'$ is the Godel number of $\neg \varphi$ whenever $k$ is the Godel number of $\varphi$).
- $\omega$-consistency is messier to state precisely, but not hard: the definition is, again, directly in terms of the provability predicate ("if $T$ proves $\varphi(k)$ for each $k$, then it does not prove $\exists x(\neg\varphi(x))$").

This provability predicate itself is really the fundamental object.

---

What about soundness? Well, here we run afoul of [**Tarski's undefinability theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem): soundness talks about **truth** instead of proof, and this we can't do.

*(Actually there's a subtlety around what "expressibility" means here, but I'm ignoring that for now and treating it as a pretty informal notion. To see the issue, suppose $T$ actually is sound; then "$0=0$" expresses the soundness of $T$, since they're each true! This is obviously silly, but it takes some work to satisfyingly untangle this, which would get us off-track here.)*

However, *fragments of* soundness are indeed expressible. Of particular interest are the $\Sigma_k$-soundness principles: $T$ is $\Sigma_k$-sound iff it only proves true $\Sigma_k$ sentences. The point is that while there is no "global truth predicate," for each $k$ there is a truth predicate $True_k$ for $\Sigma_k$ formulas. (Basically, $True_k$ is itself $\Sigma_k$, so we never "catch our tail").